# changing the default jvm in windows

Tags: java, windows, jvm, environment-variables, java-home

I installed java 8 and I need java 7. So when I changed JAVA_HOME, CLASSPATH and path I thought the default jvm would automatically change, but it didn't.
How can I change it?

Comment: The default jvm for what? Windows itself does not know any default Java VM.

Comment: Have you tried reopening your command prompt?

Comment: This happened to me too about three - four months ago. When I installed Java 8, before uninstall it I couldn't find a way to use Java 7. As @Heifa said, I have set java home, classpath  and path according to java 7. But nothing changed. In some way, windows see java 8.

Comment: CLASSPATH system variable is not actually required. If you have one, JAVA_HOME need not be in that. And I hope you have used JAVA_HOME to set Path variable. Are you confused? Default JVM? You seem to be new to Java. I hope you are right with your basics. Well, as @Danielson mentioned please open new instance of Command prompt and verify.

Comment: Actually it was Talend Install telling me that the default jvm found was 8. I uninstalled everything related to java8 and now everything is fine :) Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change in java control Panel under main control Panel